# 'System.Web.Script.Services' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've noticed I'm getting a compiler warning message:

Warning: BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Web.Script.Services' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Below are the sections from the web.config file....does system.web.extensions not take care of this?

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
         <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
  <system.web>


<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" maxRequestLength="2048" />

<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <remove name="HttpSoap"/>
    <remove name="HttpPost"/>
    <remove name="HttpGet"/>
    <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
    <remove name="Documentation"/>
    <add name="HttpSoap"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
    <add name="Documentation"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>


<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="70"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>

<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms defaultUrl="dashboard.aspx" loginUrl="index.aspx" slidingExpiration="true"  timeout="60">

  </forms>

</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok resolved now. Created new asp.net 3.5 website as my and copied and pasted a few sections relating to the system.web.extensions into the live one.